# selecting duplicate columns in psql then sorting by row id

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have tried searching the web and whilst there are plenty of answers for finding duplicates, I am yet to stumble on one that allows me to find all the duplicates within a column (i.e where the same 'name' occurs more than once) and then only select the lowest row id (which would be the first duplicate name entered).

So the table's description (inserted from a file):
create table customer(id int, name varchar,)

```
id| name

1 | Darren
2 | Mark
3 | Julie
4 | Mark
5 | Julie
```

The query:

```
CREATE VIEW AS
SELECT COUNT(name), name
FROM customer
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
```

Result (the order is never guaranteed, I want Mark to always come first as he has the lowest id):
Julie
Mark

Now the issue is, if i select id I have to include it in the group by. Doing that means no duplicate columns get selected as there wont be any since ever id is unique. And without selecting id I cant ORDER BY desc.

I hope I am clear, if not I can re-word or supply more information.

Comment: `ORDER BY MIN(id)`?

Comment: I think that you mean `Warren has the lowest`

Comment: @Hackerman, lowest id of the returned names.

Comment: @jarlh I can't order by MIN(id) without first selecting it and then grouping it with name :-( and doing that stops me finding duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this?  Nested query.  Basically the SELECT/GROUP is called.  On the outside, we get the information selected and sort it.

```
CREATE VIEW AS
SELECT CNT_NAME, NAME
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(name) CNT_NAME, name, min(id) min_id
FROM customer
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
) AS alias
ORDER BY MIN_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. I shall try and i'll let you know the result shortly.

Comment: It works!! You're a star. If i had enough rep i'd upvote your answer. I only needed to edit one small thing, for some reason i kept getting an error message telling me the subquery needed an alias (i'm not sure if this will effect to everyone). But after adding an alias before ORDER BY it works perfectly. I edited the answer, i hope that's ok? (I'm quite new to posting/commenting here).

Comment: that's fine.  Can you please "Accept" the answer?  should be on an screen option...thanks

Comment: The derived table is not really necessary. You could do an `order by min(id)` directly in the original statement